# mysql error during inserting a image in mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, html, css

I am working on a website and my task is to take product image from user and store that image in the database..i am using mysql database.
My code for html form is as:-

```
      <FORM action="testimage1.php" ENCTYPE="multipart/form-data" method="post">
              <div style="font:bold 10px arial,serif;" >Product Name*</div>
              <input type="text" name="myuserName" maxlength="50" /><br />
             <div style="font:bold 10px arial,serif;" >Upload a photo</div>
               <input name="uploadimage" type="file" /></br>
              <div style="font:bold 10px arial,serif;">Product Description:</div> 
              <input type="text" name="product" value=""></br>
              <input id="submit" type="submit" value="submit" /><br />
     </FORM>
```

My code for testimage1.php is as:-

```
           require_once("dbconnect.inc.php");                       
    $db_name="thinstrokes";                                     //for localhost databasename
     $tbl_name="product";
     $db_selected=mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

    $myusername=$_POST['myusername']; 
    $mypassword=$_POST['product'];
    $filename=$_FILES['uploadimage']['tmp_name']; 
    $imgData = file_get_contents($filename);
    $size = getimagesize($filename);
    $sql = "INSERT INTO product
    (productname, image_id , image_type ,image, image_size, image_name,   productdesc)VALUES
    ('$myusername','11', '{$size['mime']}', '{$imgData}', '{$size[3]}', 
     '{$_FILES['userfile']['name']}','$productdesc')";
    $result=mysql_query($sql) or die("error in uploading/*");
```

and i am getting an error as:-error in uploading/*
how can i correct it?

Comment: change this to see what the real error is  $result=mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

Comment: Try adding `mysql_error()` in the `or die()`. Actually you shouldn't use `or die()` since it is bad practice. It kills the script. Use proper error handling in stead.

Comment: it prints error as:- MySQL server has gone away

Comment: @user1427755 Read and understand what *[MySQL server has gone away](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/gone-away.html)* is!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to change this:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO product
(productname, image_id , image_type ,image, image_size, image_name, productdesc)VALUES
('$myusername','11', '{$size['mime']}', '{$imgData}', '{$size[3]}', 
'{$_FILES['userfile']['name']}','$productdesc')";
```

with this:

```
$size_mime = mysql_real_escape_string($size['mime']);
$size3 = mysql_real_escape_string($size[3]);
$filename = mysql_real_escape_string($_FILES['userfile']['name']);
$sql = "INSERT INTO product
(productname, image_id , image_type ,image, image_size, image_name, productdesc) VALUES
('{$myusername}','11', '{$size_mime}', '{$imgData}', '{$size3}', 
'{$filename}','$productdesc')";
```

and edit this:

```
$myusername=$_POST['myusername']; 
$mypassword=$_POST['product'];
$filename=$_FILES['uploadimage']['tmp_name'];
```

with this:

```
$myusername = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['myusername']); 
$mypassword = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['product']);
$filedata = mysql_real_escape_string($_FILES['uploadimage']['tmp_name']);
```

**you should absolutely avoid sql injection!**

Comment: and in code i am printing my sql error..it is still giving....MySQL server has gone away

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape `$imgData` and ***everything else*** with `mysql_real_escape_string` before putting it into a query.

Comment: Gosh, I wonder where it went. Just how big is this image you're trying to stick in it?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [bound](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) variables.  First off you are wide open to [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks.

Suppose someone crafted a filename of `\';DROP product;` and uploaded it...

That being said, inlining binary data into a query just isn't going to work 99% of the time.

For bound parameters your query becomes something like this and you call bind_parm to attach the data to each ?.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO product (productname, image_id , image_type ,image, image_size, image_name, productdesc) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
```

Comment: i am getting error message like ...MySQL server has gone away

Comment: Try to open an image in a text editor. That's essentially what you are doing here. It's just not going to work. Use bound variables or if you must do it this way, use  bin2hex() -> http://php.net/manual/en/function.bin2hex.php on the image data before inlining it.

Answer (score 0):

First I think you should not upload images directly to Mysql. Instead use a directory and put everything there. So with that said try something like this:

```
//target to the path of my files
$target_path = "uploads/product_images/";
if(!is_dir($target_path)) mkdir($target_path);
$uploadfile = $target_path . basename($_FILES['userfile']['name']);

//Move the uploaded file to $taget_path
(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile));
```

Then you can get to the uploaded file by using the following:

```
echo "<a href=" . $target_path . basename($row['userfile']) . ">
     {$row['userfile']}</a>";
```

Comment: If you store on disk, you need to ensure the filenames are unique or one user's upload can clobber another. I'd suggest generating a filename for disk storage and use a table to store the lookup from user filename to disk filename. If you are going to have a lot of images, making subdirectories is also a good idea or you can run out of directory inodes.